# $g_{j} = \text{dim(Ker}T_{j})-\text{dim(im}T_{j-1})$, $j = 0,1,2$. Show that $g_{j} \ge 0$ for all $j$

Tags: linear-algebra

$\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}$

$g_{j} = \dim(\ker T_{j})-\dim(\im T_{j-1})$, $j = 0,1,2$. Show that $g_{j} \ge 0$ for all $j$

working on some exam practice questions and I am not sure if I have done it correctly. Would greatly appreciate some feedback if anything appears wrong. Here is the full question, and what I have attempted so far:

> Let $V_0, V_1,V_2 $ be finite dimensional vector spaces and let:
>
> $T_{-1}:\{\textbf{0}\} \rightarrow V_0, \space T_{0}:V_0 \rightarrow V_1, \space T_{1}:V_1 \rightarrow V_2, \space T_{2}:V_2 \rightarrow \{\textbf{0}\}  $ be
>   linear operators. The composition $T_1\circ T_0 : V_0 \rightarrow V_2$
>   is a linear operator mapping each $v \in V_0 $  to $T_1(T_0(v)) \in V_2.$
>
> Assume $T_1\circ T_0  = 0$ and let
>
> $g_{j} = \text{dim(Ker}T_{j})-\text{dim(im}T_{j-1})$, $j = 0,1,2$.
>
> (a) Show that $g_{j} \ge 0$ for all $j$
>
> (b) Show that $g_{0} - g_{1} + g_{2} = \text{dim}(V_0) - \text{dim}(V_1) + \text{dim}(V_2)$

Then starting with $g_2$:

$g_2 = \text{dim(ker}T_2) - \text{dim(im}T_1) $

$ \text{dim(ker}T_2) = \text{dim}(V_2) $ from the fact that  $T_2(v) = \{\textbf{0}\}$ for every $v \in V_2$, also $\text{dim(im}T_1)$ must be $ \le  \text{dim}(V_2)$. So it holds that $g_2 \ge 0$

For $g_1$:

$g_1 = \text{dim(ker}T_1) - \text{dim(im}T_0) $

$ \text{dim(ker}T_1) = \text{dim}(V_0) $ from the fact that  $T_1\circ T_0 = 0 $ for every $v \in V_0$, so I have:

$g_1 = \text{dim}(V_0) - \text{dim(im}T_0) = \text{dim}(V_0) - ( \text{dim}(V_0) - \text{dim(ker}T_0)) = \text{dim(ker}T_0) $ by the rank nullity theorem. So it holds that $g_1 \ge 0$ (since we can't have negative dimension).

Finally for $g_0$

$g_0 = \text{dim(ker}T_0) - \text{dim(imT}_{-1}) $ and by the rank nullity theorem $\text{dim(im}T_{-1}) = \text{dim}(\{\textbf{0}\}) - \text{dim(ker}T_{-1}) = 0 $. So $g_0 \ge 0$.

Would this be correct for (a)?

For (b), I have:

$g_{0} - g_{1} + g_{2} = \text{dim(ker}T_0) - \text{dim(im}T_{-1}) - \text{dim(ker}T_1) + \text{dim(im}T_0) + \text{dim(ker}T_2) - \text{dim(im}T_1)$

Then using rank nullity: $$\text{dim(ker}T_0) = \text{dim}(V_0) - \text{dim(im}T_0)$$ and $$\text{dim(ker}T_1) = \text{dim}(V_1) - \text{dim(im}T_1)$$ and from (a) $$ \text{dim(ker}T_2) = \text{dim}(V_2)$$

$$\text{dim(im}T_{-1}) = 0$$

Substituting these into the above equation yields the result. Would this be correct?

Comment: sigh...... To participate in math.stackexchange.com is to be continually amazed that people have the ability to acquire such astonishing lack of familiarity with TeX mathematical notation such as that used in MathJax.  When you write \text{dim} instead of \dim then you do not get proper spacing in expressions like $a\dim b$, and similarly with \text{Ker} instead of \ker. On the other hand, \im behaves differently, but I've created a new command and inserted it into this posting so that you can finish the editing I started.

Comment: . . . that's why you see  $\text{im}T_{j-1}$ instead of $\operatorname{im}T_{j-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're right, but let me shed a little light on what you're actually doing. You're working with something that is almost "an exact sequence", something that looks like:

$$ 0 \to V_0  \overset{ f}{\to}  V_1 \overset{g}{\to} V_2 \overset{h}{\to} 0 $$

with the condition that $g \circ f \equiv 0$, which is to say the image of $f$ $=$ the kernel of $g$ and $f$. If $f$ is injective then it is exact! There is a lot of information here using the rank nullity theorem here. For instance, we have ( where $| \cdot|$ stands for dimension)

$$|V_0| = |\text{im}(f) | + | \ker (f) | =|\ker(g)| + | \ker(f) | $$
$$|V_1| =|\text{im}(g) | + | \ker (g) | $$

$$\implies |V_0|-|V_1| = |\ker (f)| - | \text{im}(g) |$$

Since we have that $h$ is the zero map, we have that $h \circ g \equiv 0$ which means that the image of $g$ = kernel of $h$ (which is everything!). So we see that

$$ |V_2| = |\ker(h)| = |\text{im}(g)| $$

$$\implies |V_0|-|V_1| + |V_2| = |\ker(f) |$$

If $f$ were injective, the kernel is empty so we see the alternating sum of dimensions is zero! Just thought I'd share the insight.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. That's great.